# Getting zip-code + 4 from latitude/longitude

Tags: iphone, geolocation

Does anyone know the best way to use the iPhone location services (lat/long) to determine the zip code+4 of the user? Does MKReverseGeocoder have the ability to pull back zip+4?

Thanks!

-tony

Answer (score 2):

My favorite place to go for anything having to do with geocoding is [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a free Reverse Geocoding service to do this for you.

Google has such a service: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#ReverseGeocoding

Alternately, this Google Groups post has a listing of other Reverse Geocoding services: http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/web/resources-non-google-geocoders?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKPlacemark/postalCode) says that the MKPlacemark that MKReverseGeocoder only returns a five-digit zip code. You may have to use an outside reverse geocoder as described in the other answers to get the extra four digits.